# Disk usage by application in Windows XP

Tags: process, windows-xp, disk

Most process-monitoring software can show CPU(s) load by application in real-time.
But I can't find anything that could show me real-time Disk(s) usage by applications (hard disks, CDs/DVDs, flash drives, etc.).

There is program [***AnVir Task Manager***](http://www.anvir.net/) that can show harddisk load but it shows it at all not by each app or process.

On the other side there is utility from [***Sysinternals***](http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/bb545027) called ***Filemon*** (now ***Process Monitor***) that shows all activity with filesystem (reading/writing files) with processes and paths but this information is too verbose.

I think I'm looking for software that can show me the table like below:

_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

Process        |   Disk Usage (%)   |   Disk/Partition            |   Some info..  |

_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _  |

uTorrent.exe   |        68                   |   Harddisk1/Partition0 |   blah-blah-5  |

_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _  |

Applic-9.exe   |        17                   |   Harddisk1/Partition1 |   bloh-bloh-5   |

_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _  |

Please, tell if you know that kind of software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from [here](https://serverfault.com/a/4810/131157):

You can view the IO usage in the system tray using [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) by enabling "Options->I/O History Tray Icon".

Hover over the icon, and it will tell you which app is using the most IO right now.

Comment: I'm really sorry for duplicate. I'd only searched in SO. And thank you a lot!